# How to fix org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException in elasticsearch 1.5.1

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

Hi all I have updated the elastic search version from `1.2.2` to `1.5.1`. When I rebuild the code using maven it shows `org. elastic search. client.transport. NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available`.

Even I also try to change the `spring-data-elasticsearch` to `1.3.1`.
But it always shows the same error again and again. How could I fix this?

Comment: Make sure the versions are compatible; maybe you have less nodes than it's required for consistency?

Comment: Hi Felipe Almeida Thanks for your response.i'm new in elastic search. I don't know how to assign the required node  will you help me to fix this.And how do i identify the versions are compatible ?.